# SharePoint 2010 central admin configuration wizard remotely

Tags: central-administration, configuration-wizard

I'm trying to open the Configuration Wizard page in SharePoint 2010 Central Administration from a remote computer in the net, but all I get is a blank page.

Are there problems opening the central administration from a remote computer, should this work? If so, what can be the problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: nothing in SharePoint will prevent you to open the CA from a remote computer. You should try classic approachs of HTTP connectivity troubleshooting. Possible causes are numerous: NTLM and Kerberos misconfiguration, firewall issue, dns issue, corporate reverse proxy issue, alien invasion, authorization issue, Internet explorer configuration, etc.